# Insert table from gmail to google spreadsheet by google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recive an email with table many times in one day it can be 10x2 or 40x2 or something like this. Every time I need to paste this table in sheet start from cell A1/ Now I have this code, but it paste whole table to cell A1:

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:inbox is:unread to:me subject:importnumbers";

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708

function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}  
  function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {

      sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValues(array2d);
      }

    function saveEmails() {
        var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
        if (array2d) {
            appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('numberlist'), array2d);
        }
      markArchivedAsRead ();
    }

    function markArchivedAsRead() {
      var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox is:unread to:me subject:importnumberlist');
      GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
    };
```

Please, help me to paste table with right dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

1. Replace `getEmails_(q)` function

**Code#1:**

```
function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {

            var arrStr = msgs[j].getBody()
              .replace(/<\/tr>/gm, '[/tr]')
              .replace(/<\/td>/gm, '[/td]')
              .replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
              .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '')
              .replace(/^\s*/gm, '')
              .replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
              .split("[/tr]");

            var line = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length - 1; i++) {

              line = arrStr[i].split("[/td]");
              line.length -= 1;
              emails.push(line);
            }
        }
    }
    return emails;
}
```

2. Replace `appendData_` function

**Code#2:**

```
 function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {

    var h = array2d.length;
    var l = array2d[0].length;

    sheet.getRange(1, 1, h, l).setValues(array2d);
 }
```

This code converts the html text into 2d array and then paste it into Spreadsheet.

## Note 2020-06

Your email may (1) contain several tables or (2) a table with merged cells. In this case, the proposed script may cause an error:

> The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns
>   in the range

In this situation, you'll need to create another function to parse the message body. I suggest you see the HTML-code of your message and inspect it in Gmail:

Right Click > Instect

or [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[I]

The other approach in this situation is to paste data "as is", use sample function to convert any 2d array into rectangular:

```
function convert2ArrayToRectangular_(array2d)
{
  // get max width
  var res = [];
  var w = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
  {
    if (array2d[i].length > w) {w = array2d[i].length;}    
  }

  var row = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
  {
    row = array2d[i];
    if(array2d[i].length < w)
    {
      for (var ii = array2d[i].length; ii < w; ii++)
      {
        row.push('');        
      }  
    }
    res.push(row);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
function test_get_email() {
  var q = 'Test_table_to_sheets';
  var array2d = getEmails_(q);  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BKkd5LwBYyGoi2um-S3pTCBKrUEko34m9vJu94K8uOQ').getSheetByName('Test_table_to_sheets2');
  appendData_(sheet, convert2ArrayToRectangular_(array2d));
}
```

Comment: Hello, Max! Thak you for answer, but I have one trouble: when cell in email look like 6679027476when I import it to google sheet, it became this: <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">6679027476<u></u><u></u></span></p> . Cells which I recive by email its just a copy from excel.

Comment: And in top left cell this: <div dir="ltr"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><colgroup><col width="858"><col width="100"></colgroup><tbody>8019°

Comment: I've made some changes to `getEmails_(q)`. Please, try now. If it won't help, please, give me Excel file sample with remainrd formatting to test the code.

Comment: Hello, again Max! I have only one issue - every cell after import look like this, except top left, it have only one "next line" symbol after text, when other cells have this symbol before and after text:
"
2510-0169
"
every cell send by outlook, without any formating. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, I just add .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "") to getEmails_(q) and it work !

Comment: Hi @MaxMakhrov, I'm trying to use this also but I'm getting the following error:

Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 4. (line 38, file "ImportTable")

I've tried changing numRows to 2 instead of h but then get an error stating 'The data has 4 but the range has 2.  If I change numRows to 4 it says 'The data has 2 but the range has 4'.

Comment: Hi @peter-chabot, I'm sorry but your case appears to be 1 of the following: (1) more than 1 table in a message, or (2) a table with merged cells. In this case, it may be difficult to retrieve the tabular info from the message. There are a few things you could do with it. I supposed in the update possible solutions. Please see the answer.

Comment: Thank you @MaxMakhrov, i'm getting an undefined error on ```var l = array2d[0].length;``` ```TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.)```

Comment: array2d is undefined for some reason. You could check it with `console.log`

Comment: I used Logger.log but it's not printing anything extra besides the same error to Apps Scripts Logs.

Comment: There's a standard debugging process on errors like yours. Here's the sample article related to your problem: https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/03/13/cannot-call-method-of-null-solved-google-apps-script/