# How to automatically copy a table from email body to Google Sheets?

Tags: parsing, google-sheets, gmail

I am receiving daily reports that are in the form of Excel table in the body of the mail. Is there a way to automatically get that table and put it in a Google sheet?

I literally haven't tried anything as I don't know where to start.

Comment: you could import your inbox messages into Google Sheets (for starters)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You could start by searching for a sample script that does what you're looking for or close to it, then post here if you have any issues with it.

Comment: I have tried looking for something similar, but so far can't find :(

Comment: Start by looking for a script to find the email you're looking for and add the contents to a sheet, there are plenty of them on this site alone.

Comment: I tried using this and it works, but it imports only the subject and not the body of the mail itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857494/import-emails-that-fit-criteria-to-google-spreadsheet-using-apps-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert table from gmail to google spreadsheet by google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072161/insert-table-from-gmail-to-google-spreadsheet-by-google-script)