# Is it possible to export table from Gmail body while preserving the format, to Google sheets using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, html-email, cell-formatting

I am trying to get data from Gmail body using GAS. To be specific, I get an email with a table content; I am trying to copy the table from gmail and write it to google sheet for my further analysis. Below is a sample email I get:
[image]

The output I am expecting in Google sheets:
[image]

UPDATE: I was able to make some modifications to the code I had by referring to [Insert table from gmail to google spreadsheet by google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072161/insert-table-from-gmail-to-google-spreadsheet-by-google-script)

Here's how the email body and output looks like now.
Email:
[image]

GSheet Output:
[image]

The issue occurs with merged cells in table. The code does not generate output as how it appears in the gmail body. Is there any workaround  for this?

Final code:

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "SearchKey";

function getEmailss_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    if (threads.length == 0) {
      console.log("No threads found that match the search query: " + q);
    }
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            var arrStr = msgs[j].getBody()
              .replace(/<\/tr>/gm, '[/tr]')
              .replace(/<\/td>/gm, '[/td]')
              .replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
              .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '')
              .replace(/^\s*/gm, '')
              .replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
              .split("[/tr]");
            if (arrStr.length == 1) {
              console.log("No data found in thread: " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
            }
            var line = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length - 1; i++) {

              line = arrStr[i].split("[/td]");
              line.length -= 1;
              emails.push(line);
            }
        }
    }
    if (emails.length == 0) {
      console.log("No emails found that match the search query: " + q);
    }
    return convert2ArrayToRectangular_(emails);
}

function convert2ArrayToRectangular_(array2d)
{
  // get max width
  var res = [];
  var w = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
  {
    if (array2d[i].length > w) {w = array2d[i].length;}    
  }

  var row = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
  {
    row = array2d[i];
    if(array2d[i].length < w)
    {
      for (var ii = array2d[i].length; ii < w; ii++)
      {
        row.push('');        
      }  
    }
    res.push(row);
  }
  return res;
}


function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    var h = array2d.length;
    var l = array2d[0].length;
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, h, l).setValues(array2d);
 } 

function saveEmailsss() {
    var array2d = getEmailss_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'), convert2ArrayToRectangular_(array2d));
    }
    markArchivedAsRead();
}

function markArchivedAsRead() {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox is:unread to:me subject:importnumberlist');
    GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what are the differences between the top and bottom images. Please describe the table design specification using text.

Comment: Please bear in mind that formated messages in Gmail uses HTML while Google Sheets uses SpreadheetApp.Range methods.

Comment: The first image is a preview from Gmail. That's a sample of how I get the email. The second one is how I want that table from Gmail to be pulled into google sheet in different columns&rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert table from gmail to google spreadsheet by google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072161/insert-table-from-gmail-to-google-spreadsheet-by-google-script)

Comment: Hi Lorena, have made changes to my question. Yes, the other question was helpful to a great extent; but stuck with a new problem now. Please refer to my updated question - if you could guide on what can be done on this, it would be really helpful

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another approach, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, the HTML table can be parsed by including the merged cells. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

This script uses Sheets API. [Please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
var SEARCH_QUERY = "SearchKey";

function getEmailss_(q, sheetName) {
  var emails = [];
  var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
  if (threads.length == 0) {
    console.log("No threads found that match the search query: " + q);
  }
  var tables = [];
  for (var i in threads) {
    var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j in msgs) {
      var arrStr = msgs[j].getBody();
      var table = arrStr.match(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/);
      if (table) {
        tables.push(table[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  if (emails.length == 0) {
    console.log("No emails found that match the search query: " + q);
  }
  if (tables.length == 0) {
    console.log("No tables.");
    return
  };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var requests = [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: tables.join(""), coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() } } }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}

function saveEmailsss() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  getEmailss_(SEARCH_QUERY, sheetName);
  markArchivedAsRead();
}
```

- When this script is run, the HTML table included in the email message is retrieved and put to the active Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: Amazing - this worked!! Thank you so much! 
 
only had to remove "if (tables.length == 0) { console.log("No tables.");" and change emails.length to tables.length in the line before.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I had a quick question. I'm using "sheet.getRange("A1:E").clearContent();" before "var requests" to clear the existing table and write the new output. 
However, I can see that after the data gets added, it immediately gets deleted and the table formatting stays. Would you be familiar with such an issue? Is this causing because of Sheets API?

Comment: Also, as a temp workaround, I am deleting the first 4 columns and adding back another 4 columns to make it appear that the data is new every time the code is run. I am using the following codes:
sheet.deleteColumns(1, 4)
sheet.insertColumns(1, 4);

Comment: @Gitz About your new question of `I had a quick question.`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: When I run the code, I want the existing data to be cleared from "Sheet1". The new data should be written after that. 
I tried adding "sheet.getRange("A1:E").clearContent();" but it's not working.

Comment: @Gitz Thank you for replying. About your new question, unfortunately, I cannot still understand it. I'm worried that I might trouble you because I cannot resolve your various questions soon. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'd be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Added a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142872/unable-to-clear-the-contents-in-the-sheet-while-using-sheets-api-in-google-appsc
Thanks.